# Laravel view receives a variable that is not being passed to it

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm having a strange problem that causes a variable to be passed to a sub-view even if it's not actually defined in the parent view.

This is the code I'm using to include the view using Blade syntax:

```
@include('segments/tasksList')
```

But if it execute the following code in `segments/tasksList.blade.php`

```
<++ dd($user) ++>
```

I get `bool(true)` as a result.

Don't mind `<++ ++>` I changed the Blade syntax because it was interfering with AngularJS.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your code you have `View::share('user', ...)` which exposes a variable to all views even though it's not explicitly passed to the view. 

Do you get the same result if you `dd($some_variable_that_definitely_does_not_exist)`?

Comment: You're right, if I try using another variable then I receive `bool(false)` but now the problem is where could that `$user` variable defined? I never used the `View::share()` function.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? I suppose that `$user` is 'reserved' the same way as `$errors`, which, on a dump, should give you an empty `MessageBag` instance (unless it contains anything obviously). Are you using `Auth`?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 4.2. Yes, I'm using `Auth` but in that case I don't need an instance of the authenticated user. Anyway in my ViewController I was mistakenly using: `return View::make('pages/company', ['user' => Auth::user()]);` and by removing `, ['user' => Auth::user()]` the `$user` variable is no longer defined. Could it be that it was propagating to all the sub-views?

Comment: Yes, the view variables are certainly passed through to the subviews.

Comment: OK, thank you! I thought that the variables where limited to the current view and I needed to pass them again to sub-views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Denker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152440/dencker) I noticed that in my controller I had

```
return View::make('pages/company', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

that was causing the `$user` variable to be passed to all sub-views.